# Using Python with Pandas to output random rows from two columns

Tags: python, excel, pandas, random

I have a spreadsheet with three columns. I want to output an n number of random rows, and this works for outputting any amount of random rows from one column:

```python
    df = pandas.read_excel(filename, header=0, names=["Speaker","Time","Message"])
    random.choices(df["Message"], k=10)
```

From what I've read, you should be able to select multiple columns by doing this:

```python
    df = pandas.read_excel(filename, header=0, names=["Speaker","Time","Message"])
    random.choices(df[["Speaker","Message"]], k=10)
```

But this gives me a keyerror. I'm not sure what I'm missing. Other examples seem to make it pretty straightforward, but I must be missing something, probably extremely simple.

Thanks.

Comment: Would [.sample()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sample.html) achieve the same thing? `df[["Speaker","Message"]].sample(n=10, random_state=1)`

Comment: @MDR you beat me :D

Comment: @Emma Well no, comments are not made for giving answers, so you did the right thing ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

random.choices is for list-like 1 demential data (ie: list, tuple, etc). It won't work for dataframes where you have a 2 demential data (row x column).

If you like to have random picks from dataframe, you can use pandas `sample` function.

```
df.sample(10)
```

or to get specific columns.

```
df[['Speaker', 'Message']].sample(10)
```

Comment: Oh my god, thanks so much. This works! I guess I should have looked up the attributes of df, it seems. I appreciate it.